# checking from which page this page was navigated

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app in Windows Phone 8

and at some point i need a code to tell me

if the **page** am working on was **navigated** from "the page i want"
or If it's the **start-up page**

I checked all Events , there is no one with what i need

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current URL of page like this,

```
 Uri currentUri = ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.CurrentSource;
```

Comment: is it the url of the page that navigated to the page am working on?

Comment: Current url that user is In, you can use this and use a logic to track!

Comment: How ?  i don't understand how i can access the page i want

Comment: and The code doesn't work too
error: 
`Member 'BrainTrain.App.RootFrame.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name`

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better for you to include the information in the url navigation string. And tap into the events navigating from and to the pages.

Look at [this link](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-18-Navigating-Between-Pages) where you will be walked through what is possible when you navigate!